# Decrease the default fontsize \sf series

Tags: fonts

Say, my default fontseries is textrm with fontsize 10. Now, if I use `\textsf{text}` for certain texts, then the typeset sf font  looks larger than the default text fontsize. What is the best way to reduce the default fontsize of all `\textsf` in the document.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\begin{document}
This is normal text and I want to reduce the fontsize of \textsf{this text}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us *which* Serif (Roman) font and *which* sans-serif font you employ. Is it Computer Modern Roman and Computer Modern Sans, or maybe something else?

Comment: I am not sure which one I used; I used the default.